# Options Configuration with dynamic (runtime) values

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MySettings class which I want to configure as Options to make it available via the dependency injection.

Currently I do (in an service builder extension method):

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(configuration.GetSection(MySettings.CustomSectionName));
```

My problem is that one part of the settings comes from the appsettings and other values are only known at runtime (startup).

So I try to find out how to configure the settings with adding the runtime provided values. I tried to add the values to the configuration

```
configuration["SectionName:ValueX"] = "my runtime value";
```

That did not work and ValueX is always null (when the options are injected in the controller).

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: You not necessarily need to use the `Options`. If I got it right, you can bind the section to your class, get a hold of an instance of it, add more configs and then register it yourself in the DI container as a Singleton. Can  you explain better how are these other "runtime" values are obtained?

Comment: well, the value is just a hardcoded name (used at multiple places) which should not be changeable outside of code (aka via config). Its up to the user of the library what value is taken (in Startup.ConfigureServices). I prefer the assembly name, guid or a hardcoded string.

Comment: Ah I see. So you have your configs, but then the consumer can add more things and you want to somehow merge them together?

Comment: ahm yes. for now i have the service builder extension method (for adding the service) which takes ValueX as string, validates it, throws exception if it is invalid. I just don't get this one value into the config (within the extension method) so it is set when the controller gets the options injected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IPostConfigureOptions< TOptions >** interface to achieve what you want

```
services.PostConfigure<CustomOptions>(customOptions =>
{
    customOptions.Option1 = "post_configured_option1_value";
});
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#options-post-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You could try register `MySettings` instead of `IOptions<MySettings>` like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{          
    var mySettings = new MySettings();
    Configuration.Bind("MySettings", mySettings);
    mySettings.Title = "Hello";
    services.AddSingleton(mySettings);
}
```

And use `MySettings` like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MySettings _settings;
    public HomeController(MySettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(_settings);
    }
```